# generating ranking numbers by a value

Tags: javascript, sorting

Given a set of `Objects` with a name and a score each:

```
[
    {score: 14, name:"apple"}
    {score: 13, name:"orange"}
    {score: 11, name:"banana"}
    {score: 11, name:"cabbage"}
    {score: 11, name:"bread"}
    {score: 2,  name:"cherry"}
    {score: 2,  name:"cheese"}
]
```

How would I generate a ranking number like this:

```
[
    {rank: 1, score: 14, name:"apple"}
    {rank: 2, score: 13, name:"orange"}
    {rank: 3, score: 11, name:"banana"}
    {rank: 3, score: 11, name:"cabbage"}
    {rank: 3, score: 11, name:"bread"}
    {rank: 6, score: 2,  name:"cherry"}
    {rank: 6, score: 2,  name:"cheese"}
]
```

Because some of them objects tie, they get the same number and the ones after are offset.

Comment: You'll probably need to `forEach` and update rank after sort. What have you tried so far BTW?

Comment: @Tao I've tried to use a for look and decrement `i` anytime a number is the same as the last one, but I'm not sure how to make it offset back to normal. My method did [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6] whereas it should have done [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 9].

Comment: Do you care about sorting within the "rank"?

Comment: @Wayne No, in my application it's done already. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Array.map` with some logic will do the trick:

```
var ranked = data.map(function(item, i) {
    if (i > 0) {
        //Get our previous list item
        var prevItem = data[i - 1];
        if (prevItem.score == item.score) {
            //Same score = same rank
            item.rank = prevItem.rank;
        } else {
            //Not the same score, give em the current iterated index + 1
            item.rank = i + 1;
        }
    } else {
        //First item takes the rank 1 spot
        item.rank = 1;
    }

    return item;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/s0zvfubn/1/

```js
var data = [
    {score: 14, name:"apple"},
    {score: 13, name:"orange"},
    {score: 11, name:"banana"},
    {score: 11, name:"cabbage"},
    {score: 11, name:"bread"},
    {score: 2,  name:"cherry"},
    {score: 2,  name:"cheese"}
]

var ranked = data.map(function(item, i) {
    if (i > 0) {
        var prevItem = data[i - 1];
        if (prevItem.score == item.score) {
            item.rank = prevItem.rank;
        } else {
            item.rank = i + 1;
        }
    } else {
        item.rank = 1;
    }
    
    return item;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(ranked, null, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: At first, it didn't increment after repeating the number, but I see you've edited it. Thanks!

Comment: @Poyo -- Haha yeah - I didnt realize the rank was offset, but that was an easy fix